# True or False: $f$ is injective if and only if $f^*$ is surjective where $f^*$ is corresponding to the pullback to $f$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of affine varieties and $f^*: A(Y)\rightarrow A(X)$ the corresponding homomorphism of the coordinate rings. The question is whether this is true or false:

$f$ is injective if and  only if $f^*$ is surjective.

The "only if" part is false. Here is a counterexample:

$$X=\mathbb{A^1}, Y=V(x^2-y^3)\\
f: X\rightarrow Y, t \rightarrow (t^3,t^2)\\
f^*: A(Y)\rightarrow A(X), (\bar{x},\bar{y})\rightarrow (t^3,t^2)$$
In this example $f$ is bijective, but $f^*$ is not surjective, since it does not map anything to $t$.

I cannot prove the "if" part or construct a counterexample of it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, without loss of generality, we may assume $Y = \mathbb{A}^n$ for some $n$. Do you agree?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thank you for your reply! Are you saying the statement is false and use $Y=\mathbb{A}^n$ as a counterexample? If it is true, why can we just assume $Y=\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: If $f^*$ is surjective, then $f$ is a closed embedding ($X \cong \mathrm{Spec}(A(Y)/\ker f^*)$), in particular injective.

Comment: @KittyL The claim is correct. Since $Y$ is affine, you may embed it in some $\mathbb{A}^n$. The claim is that $X$ embeds in the same $\mathbb{A}^n$, and moreover $X \subseteq Y$ under this embedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f^\ast$ is surjective and let us prove that $f$ is injective. Let $x_1,x_2\in X$ be two points with $y:=f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Assume that $x_1\ne x_2$, then there is some function (the restriction of some coordinate function, say) $\varphi\in A(X)$ with $\varphi(x_1)\ne\varphi(x_2)$. However, $f^\ast$ is surjective, so there is some $\psi\in A(Y)$ with $f^\ast(\psi)=\varphi$. This implies 
$$\psi(y)=\psi(f(x_1))=f^\ast(\psi)(x_1)=\varphi(x_1)\ne\varphi(x_2)=f^\ast(\psi)(x_2)=\psi(f(x_2))=\psi(y),$$
which is a blatant contradiction. We must have had $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Of course, you can easily turn this into a direct proof, which is then more elegant. But it is late, and I will leave you with this.

Comment: Is it true also that $f$ must be an isomorphism? And that's the reason that the injective $f$ in the OP does not produce a surjective $f^*$?

Comment: Dear @JKEG, I don't quite understand your follow-up question, but I suggest you ask it as an actual question (if you can't find an existing question here that is equivalent), and then leave a link here to that question.